# Thymeleaf: Input cannot be null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, аутентификация

Выдает ошибку `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input cannot be null` в этом файле index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Собаки</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if "${isUserAuth}">Выйти</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Данные должны браться из этого контроллера:

```
package com.example.demo6.controller;

import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class DogController {
    
@GetMapping("/")
public static String index(Model model) {   
    model.addAttribute("isUserAuth", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());   
    return "index";
}
}
```

Что я не так сделал?

Comment: Символ "=" после `th:if`.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!